# How to convert Vec<char> to a string

Tags: string, rust

How to convert `Vec<char>` to string form so that I can print it?

Answer (score 194):

Use `collect()` on an iterator:

```
let v = vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let s: String = v.into_iter().collect();
println!("{}", s);
```

The original vector will be consumed. If you need to keep it, use `v.iter()`:

```
let s: String = v.iter().collect();
```

There is no more direct way because `char` is a 32-bit Unicode scalar value, and strings in Rust are sequences of bytes (`u8`) representing text in UTF-8 encoding. They do not map directly to sequences of `char`s.

Comment: If you don't want to use `s` and only need this string temporarily, you could do this: `v.iter().collect::<String>()`

Comment: btw, `::<>` is called `turbofish` in Rust.

Answer (score 54):

Here is a more readable version that consumes the vector:

```
use std::iter::FromIterator;

fn main() {
    let v = vec!['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
    let s = String::from_iter(v);
    // vs
    let s: String = v.into_iter().collect();
}
```

Note that `collect` is implemented with a call to `FromIterator::from_iter`:

```
fn collect<B: FromIterator<Self::Item>>(self) -> B
where
    Self: Sized,
{
    FromIterator::from_iter(self)
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to consume the vector, you can call `String::from_iter(&v)`