# Creating a string from Vec<char>

Tags: string, rust

I've got a `Vec<char>` that I need to turn into a `&str` or `String`, but I'm unsure of the best way to do this. I've looked around and every resource I've found seems to be out-dated in some way. The answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23430735/how-to-convert-vecchar-to-a-string) don't seem to be applicable for the newest build.

I'm using the nightly for 2015-3-19

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The iterator based approach with `.collect` should work, after updating for language changes:

```
char_vector.iter().cloned().collect::<String>();
```

(I've chosen to replace `.map(|c| *c)` with `.cloned()` but either works.)

Answer (score 10):

If your vector can be consumed, you can also use `into_iter` to avoid the `clone`

```
fn main() {
    let char_vector = vec!['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'];
    let str: String = char_vector.into_iter().collect();

    println!("{}", str);
}
```

Comment: In this case, the clone is of a `char`, which is super cheap (it'll compile down to just a pointer dereference, taking the char from memory into a (4-byte) register). Of course, avoiding clones is often important for perfromance, but `char` isn't such a type, and relinquishing control of the `Vec` may not be desirable.

Comment: Didn't know for the super cheap part. Just wanted to provide alternatives for clone which could help in other less cheap situations

Answer (score 7):

You can convert the `Vec` into a `String` without doing any allocations. It requires quite some unsafe code though:

```
#![feature(raw, unicode)]
use std::raw::Repr;
use std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut;

fn inplace_to_string(v: Vec<char>) -> String {
    unsafe {
        let mut i = 0;
        {
            let ch_v = &v[..];
            let r = ch_v.repr();
            let p: &mut [u8] = from_raw_parts_mut(r.data as *mut u8, r.len*4);
            for ch in ch_v {
                i += ch.encode_utf8(&mut p[i..i+4]).unwrap();
            }
        }
        let p = v.as_ptr();
        let cap = v.capacity()*4;
        std::mem::forget(v);
        let v = Vec::from_raw_parts(p as *mut u8, i, cap);
        String::from_utf8_unchecked(v)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let char_vector = vec!['h', 'ä', 'l', 'l', 'ö'];
    let str: String = char_vector.iter().cloned().collect();
    let str2 = inplace_to_string(char_vector);

    println!("{}", str);
    println!("{}", str2);
}
```

[PlayPen](http://is.gd/6XfNtE)

## Detailed Explanation

This creates a mutable `u8` slice and a `char` slice simultaneously to the same buffer (breaking all Rust guarantees). Note that the `u8` slice is four times as large as the `char` slice, since `char` always takes up 4 bytes.

```
let ch_v = &v[..];
let r = ch_v.repr();
let v: &mut [u8] = from_raw_parts_mut(r.data as *mut u8, r.len*4);
```

We need that to iterate over the unicode chars and replace them by their utf8 encoded counterpart. Since utf8 is always shorter or the same length as unicode, we can guarantee that we never overwrite any part we haven't read yet.

```
for ch in ch_v {
    i += ch.encode_utf8(&mut v[i..i+4]).unwrap();
}
```

Since a `char` is always unicode and our buffer is always exactly 4 bytes (which is the maximum number of bytes a utf8 encoded unicode char will need), we can encode our chars to utf8 without checking if it worked (it will always work). The `encode_utf8` function returns the length of the utf8 representation. Our index `i` is the location of the last written utf8 char.

Finally we need to do some cleaning up. Our vector is still of type `Vec<char>`. We get all the info we need (Pointer to the heap allocated array and the capacity)

```
let p = v.as_ptr();
let cap = v.capacity()*4;
```

Then we release the previous vector from all obligations like freeing memory.

```
std::mem::forget(v);
```

and finally recreate the u8 vector with correct length and capacity, and directly turn it into a String. The conversion to String does not need to be checked, as we already know the utf8 is correct, since the original `Vec<char>` could only contain correct unicode chars.

```
let v = Vec::from_raw_parts(p as *mut u8, i, cap);
String::from_utf8_unchecked(v)
```

Comment: Oh, right, I misread the constructor (it multiplies the capacity by the element size, but only uses that for the allocation size, not for the capacity). Well, now we have an instructive example why `unsafe` should not be used lightly ;-) The fix should be easy though, see the documentation of `Vec::from_raw_parts`.

Comment: Neat trick. "Since our chars are definitely unicode, we can encode them to utf8 without checking if it worked": fwiw, `encode_utf8` operates on `char`s, which are always valid unicode: the error is if the input buffer is too short (e.g. trying to write a 4 byte code point into `&mut v[i..i + 2]`).