# Declare String using char constants in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm looking for ways to declare `String` constants in Rust by concatenating `char`s.

What I would like to achieve is something like this:

```pascal
{ Pascal Code }
const ESC = #27;
const RESET_PRINTER = ESC + '@';
```

Here's where I ended for now after few hours of research:

```rust
const ESC: char  = '\u{001b}';

const RESET_PRINTER_ARR: [char; 2] = [ESC, '@'];
const RESET_PRINTER_STR: &str = "\u{001b}@"; // ESC + '@' ?

fn cde_str(cde: &[char], len: usize) -> String {
    let mut s = String::from("");
    for i in 0..len {
        s.push(cde[i]);
    }
    s
}

fn main() {
  let r1 = cde_str(&RESET_PRINTER_ARR, RESET_PRINTER_ARR.len()); 
  println!("{}", r1);
  
  let r2 = String::from(RESET_PRINTER_STR); 
  println!("{}", r2);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=376d1b9592fccc6aaf0fe2035af365da)

**Edit**

Per [@e-net4-stays-away-from-meta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233251/e-net4-stays-away-from-meta) suggestion a `String` can easily be created from `[char]` by using `String::from_iter()` :

```rust
use std::iter::FromIterator;

const ESC: char = '\u{001b}';
const RESET_PRINTER_ARR: [char; 2] = [ESC, '@'];

fn main() {
  let r0 = String::from_iter(&RESET_PRINTER_ARR);
  println!("{}", r0);
}
```

Comment: The same principle of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23430735) may apply: create an iterator of `char`s, then collect it.

Comment: I can't really find the question in this post. Could you please be more explicit? Would you like to evaluate the constants at compile time?

Comment: You can also iterate `&[char]` without passing its size. Just `for c in cde {...}` or even better `cde.into_iter().collect()`

Comment: @SvenMarnach it's exactly that. The goal was to reuse a const char to make a const String , so evaluate a char concatenation for a const.

To solve this problem, i use an array and I "collect" it in a String when I need.

Comment: @aniki02 There is no such thing as a const `String` in Rust, since you can't allocate memory on the heap when creating a constant. Would a `&str` work as well for you? Would a lazily initialized static `String` fit the bill?

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes but the challenge is to reuse const char to make const &str. What do you think about my array solution ?

Comment: A `str` is actually just a byte slice (with the invariant that it is valid UTF-8), and a `char` is a 32-bit integer that represents a Unicode scalar. Therefore making a `str` from `&[char]` is actually literally the operation of UTF-8 encoding, which is a bit unnecessarily intensive. Your other options are concatenating two `str`s, or two `&[u8]`s (possibly as byte strings), but sadly neither of those operations is *currently* `const` (but this is closer to becoming possible with PRs [such as this one](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/75157)).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like these are escape sequences to send to a printer, and that kind of printer probably does not naturally work in Unicode. I would make them a byte string.

To me the natural way to write it in Rust is just like this:

```rust
const RESET_PRINTER: &[u8] = b"\x1b@";

// other examples
const TERM_BOLD: &[u8] = b"\x1b[1m";
const TERM_UNDERLINE: &[u8] = b"\x1b[4m";
```

If you're going to generate very many of them, or they are very long, you can potentially [write a macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.7.0/book/macros.html) that produces the byte string literals.

But, I would be inclined not to do the macro unless it's clearly needed: within a single crate, simple straight-line code that's a bit repetitive is often more maintainable than something that requires a reader to think about how the macro works.